# MDI Implementation in WPF

Tags: wpf, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

How can I implement an MDI application in WPF?
In windows forms I was used to write code like this:

```
Form2 oForm2 = new Form2();
            oForm2.MdiParent = this;
            oForm2.Show();
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in WPF?

Comment: There are so many similar topics on Stakoverflow.

Comment: I can't find. answer if you can

Comment: There is no such thing as MDI in WPF, but there are plenty other similar features you can use.

Comment: I will tell you what I tell most other asking questions. If you want people to put effort into helping you, at least show that you have tried to put effort into the question. I don't except everyone to have perfect English, man even my English is terrible, but you should at least format your code and list the things you have tried.

Comment: Why was this question closed as "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad"?   It seemed extremely specific to me - he gave a code sample and wanted to know how to do the same thing in WPF?   What could POSSIBLY be more clear and specific than that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no ready made built-in implementation in WPF, but there are already people who did that already from scratch, check this codeplex project:

[WPF Multiple Document Interface (MDI)](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/)

Comment: wpfmdi seems to have been abandoned according to a post on CodePlex last February.

Comment: @user316117, Yeah, but this is a Microsoft decision not the community. If you googled for few seconds you will find allot of people complained about that and created their own solutions.